# Excel VBA find and subtract from specific clusters of data

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a code that looks through many sheets in a workbook. It collects a piece of the worksheet name, which is the date and puts it into the first column headed "Date" in sheet1.

Each sheet is made up of multiple tables (which aren't formatted as such), each table has a different amount of rows but same amount of cols. It extracts the data from the bottom right of first column each sheet (in col J) and data from the left of that cell (col I). It then does J minus I and puts the data in column 2, headed "Outflows" in sheet1.

I've written a code that works perfectly and it looks like this:

```
Sub ExtractTableData()


    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim tableRange As Range
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim outflows()
    
    ReDim outflows(1 To Worksheets.Count - 1, 1 To 2)
    
    i = 1
    
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        
        If Left(ws.Name, 10) = "Semaine du" Then
            
            ' Find the last row and column of the table
            lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
            lastCol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            
            ' Subtract the last cell of the first vertical group of cells in column I from the last cell of the first vertical group of cells in column J
            outflows(i, 1) = Mid(ws.Name, 12)
            outflows(i, 2) = ws.Range("J" & ws.Cells(5, "J").End(xlDown).Row).Value - ws.Range("I" & ws.Cells(5, "J").End(xlDown).Row).Value
            i = i + 1
            
        End If
        
    Next ws
    
    ' Insert the data into Sheet1
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:B" & Worksheets.Count - 1).Value = outflows
    
End Sub
```

I was wondering if there's a way that I can rewrite this code so that it gets information from the second table of each sheet? So basically from the second cluster of vertical cells in columns I and J.

I've rewritten the code as follows,

```
Sub ExtractTableData()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim tableRange As Range
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim outflows()
    
    ReDim outflows(1 To Worksheets.Count - 1, 1 To 2)
    
    i = 1
    
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        
        If Left(ws.Name, 10) = "Semaine du" Then
            
            ' Find the last row and column of the table
            lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
            lastCol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            
            ' Subtract the last cell of the second vertical group of cells in column I from the last cell of the second vertical group of cells in column J
            outflows(i, 1) = Mid(ws.Name, 12)
            outflows(i, 2) = ws.Range("J" & ws.Cells(5, "J").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Row).Value - ws.Range("I" & ws.Cells(5, "I").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Row).Value
            i = i + 1
            
        End If
        
    Next ws
    
    ' Insert the data into Sheet1
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:B" & Worksheets.Count - 1).Value = outflows
    
End Sub
```

However, while it collects the dates from the worksheet dates correctly, it's returning zeros in the "Outflows" column in sheet1, which suggests to me that it's subtracting two zeros from each other.

So from the screenshot below, I need it to return a value of 8. Because 18 - 10 = 8

Anyone know where I might be going wrong?

Thank you very much for your help!

[image]

Comment: A sample screenshot would be useful here - does each table have consistent headers?

Comment: Hi, I've added a screenshot in the original question. Yes assume every table does have consistent headers, but the problem is that as the original data wasn't formatted as a table, I'm having to look at columns J and I.

Comment: Also, please bear in mind that there are 50+ tables that are named "Semaine du" and are followed by a date.

Comment: Why are you only extracting data from the middle table?  What about the others?

Comment: Because I only need data from that table. I've already got a code that can extract data from table1. I'm trying to write a code that can extract data from Table2. The number  of rows of Table2 varies between worksheets.

Comment: Hi Tim, I got the macro to work now and have posted what it looks like now. I was wondering if my original question "Excel VBA find and subtract from specific clusters of data" is befitting of what I was trying to do? I'm still relatively new to Stackoverlow and I want to make sure that other users are able to use it to find what they are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a more generic approach where you collect all the "TOTAL" cells on a sheet and then use that to access the col J/I values.

Eg:

```vb
Sub ExtractTableData()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, rw As Range
    Dim tableNum As Long, i As Long, colTotals As Collection
    Dim valI, valJ
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook 'or activeworkbook
    ReDim outflows(1 To wb.Worksheets.Count * 2, 1 To 2)
    
    i = 1
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If Left(ws.Name, 10) = "Semaine du" Then
            'locate all TOTAL cells in Col A
            Set colTotals = FindAll(ws.Columns("A"), "TOTAL", xlWhole)
            For tableNum = 1 To colTotals.Count
                Set rw = colTotals(tableNum).EntireRow
                Debug.Print Mid(ws.Name, 12), "Table#" & tableNum, _
                       rw.Columns("J").Value, rw.Columns("I").Value
            Next tableNum
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub

'Find all matches for `val` in `rng` and return as a Collection of cells
Public Function FindAll(rng As Range, val As String, matchType As XlLookAt) As Collection
    Dim rv As New Collection, f As Range, addr As String
    Set f = rng.Find(what:=val, after:=rng.Cells(rng.Cells.CountLarge), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=matchType, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then addr = f.Address()

    Do Until f Is Nothing
        rv.Add f
        Set f = rng.FindNext(after:=f)
        If f.Address() = addr Then Exit Do
    Loop
    Set FindAll = rv
End Function
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. I copied and pasted all of the above in a single Module. Was I meant to do that? I did this and it shows all the last values from all tables in cols I and J, but it only takes into account tables from august and only from from half way the sheet as well. What I'm trying to get the result of J - I in column B of Sheet1 which is headed "outflows". But I can essentially use the results from Immediate Window to make the calculation, I would need it to collect the data from all the worksheets. Thank you for your help Tim!

Comment: What I posted is not a complete solution - I assumed you'd be able to adapt it to your needs.  I can't see your workbook, so I can't say why it's not picking up all the worksheets.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I’m assuming this part of the code is the condition that does the operation for all worksheets that commence with “Semaine du” ‘’’ For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If Left(ws.Name, 10) = "Semaine du" Then’’’ is that correct? I’m trying to think of ways as to make sure that it collects all sheets that start with those words. Thanks!

Comment: Is the macro running in the same workbook you're collecting data from?  If it's not picking up all the expected sheets then you'd need to make sure the names really match the expected pattern

Comment: Yes, all the sheets are in the same workbook and the names match the expected pattern as the first code I wrote in my question works perfectly. Do you know what could be happening? I was wondering if there's a way to manipulate the first code so that it basically does control down arrow four times from cell J1 and I1 (which is what I basically did in the first code)? Thank you for your help Tim!

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of trial and error I finally got it to work

Since I know the space between the tables is equidistant I used the number of rows between tables to seperate them and  End(xlDown) method to find the last cell of the second vertical group of cells in columns I and J

Sub ExtractTableData2()

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim outflows()
Dim numRowsBetweenGroups As Long

ReDim outflows(1 To Worksheets.Count - 1, 1 To 2)

i = 1
numRowsBetweenGroups = 2 

For Each ws In Worksheets
    
    If Left(ws.Name, 10) = "Semaine du" Then
       
        
        ' Find the last cell of the first vertical group of cells in column I and J
        Dim lastRowGroup1 As Long
        lastRowGroup1 = ws.Range("J5").End(xlDown).Row
        
        ' Finds the next group of cells
        Dim lastRowGroup2 As Long
        lastRowGroup2 = lastRowGroup1 + numRowsBetweenGroups + ws.Range("J" & lastRowGroup1).End(xlDown).Row - lastRowGroup1
        
        ' Subtract the last cell of the second vertical group of cells in column I from the last cell of the second vertical group of cells in column J
        outflows(i, 1) = Mid(ws.Name, 12)
        outflows(i, 2) = ws.Range("J" & lastRowGroup2).End(xlDown).Value2 - ws.Range("I" & lastRowGroup2).End(xlDown).Value2
        i = i + 1
        
    End If
    
Next ws

' Insert the data into Sheet1
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:B" & Worksheets.Count - 1).Value = outflows
```

End Sub